# "As if it weren't bad enough": meaning and subjunctive mood?

Tags: meaning, subjunctive-mood

This is a sentence from a preface of book:

> *As if* it *weren’t* bad enough that I wrote my first book during our first year of marriage, I wrote this book during our first year of parenthood. Although I was able to do most of the writing after our son went to bed, I robbed the two of us of any significant quality time for far too long.

Is is my understanding that the author wants to say writing this book during the first year of parenthood is worse than before. Is that right?

I can't understand what *as if* means. Is this subjunctive mood?

Comment: I think  the authors means that it was a 'difficult experience' to write his first book during his first year of marriage. Beside that, he wrote this book during his first year of parenthood. The author is saying that he repeated the 'difficult experience' as if he had not had enough of it the first time.

Comment: Yes it is  subjunctive mood: http://www.englishcafe.jp/englishcollege/etense2/e8-2-2.html

Comment: Sorry, I update the quote content. I think he means he felt sorry for both of book writing.right ?

Comment: Or is it a joke with him which author want to say?

Comment: It appears that he actually feels sorry for having spent time writing his books instead of staying longer with his wife and his son...I can't say if he is sincere or not.

Answer (score 1):

*As if it weren't bad enough* is a phrase that will be followed by two events, one 'bad' (as in *bad enough*) and one even more so.

> As if it weren't bad enough that *I fell off the horse* (first bad event), it then *kicked me in the leg*. (second bad event)

*As* means *as though* or *like*. When you use *as if*, you can use the subjunctive, though it isn't strictly necessary, especially if there isn't anything unreal about the situation:

> - She looked through me as if *I weren't* even there (he really is there).
> - He remembered that day as if *it were* yesterday (it wasn't yesterday).
> - He laughed as if *it was* some kind of a joke.

---

> As if it weren’t bad enough that I wrote my first book *during our first year of marriage*, I wrote this book *during our first year of parenthood*.

The first year of marriage is a time to get to know your spouse, set up a home, etc. It's busy enough that writing a book is difficult. But the first year of parenthood is even busier, and an even worse time to write a book. Hence the *as if it weren't bad enough.* In doing so, s/he robbed him/herself and spouse of quality time together.

Comment: Does the quote apply the subjunctive? I think it doesn't . Right ?

Comment: Because the before one is **really** not bad enough.

Comment: @Joe.wang - I think the first situation *is* bad enough, and the second is even worse. That's the nature of using *as if it weren't bad enough...*